# Row striping with multiple tables

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have multiple tables in the same document and want add a row color starting at the first tbody row in each table.

I have the followiong code

```
$('table tbody tr').filter(':even').not('.spacer, .hidden, thead tr, tfoot tr').addClass('even');
```

However, it's not working exactly as I would like. Can anyone help with the code above so I can ensure the row highlighting starts with the first tbody row of each table, no matter how many tables appear on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check it out here: [Zebra Striping](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aZebra_Striping_Made_Easy) (From jQuery Docs).

Anyways, try this code, and it works:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table tr").mouseover(function(){$(this).addClass("over");}).mouseout(function(){$(this).removeClass("over");});
        $("table tr:even").addClass("alt");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, this selector should work for you:

```
$('table tbody tr:first-child').addClass('even');
```

#### EDIT

If you're looking to stripe every other row, starting from the first, you want this instead:

```
// ... and adding the .even class to :odd rows is just weird.
$('table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('even');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatley that just styles the first row. I need the striping to start with the first row, then style every other in each table in the document.

Comment: But that's how you phrased your question: `and want add a row color to the FIRST tbody row in each table`. :D May I suggest you edit your question to reflect what you just said?

Comment: Adding :nth-child(odd) into the code has worked.

 $('tbody tr:visible:nth-child(odd), #popUp tbody tr:nth-child(odd)').not('.uploadBtn, .spacer, .hidden, thead tr, tfoot tr').addClass('even');

Comment: ooh, that makes sense. fell for the same mistake I corrected in some other answer below. /lol

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `$('table tbody:first-child tr:first-child')` this ensure that the first row of first tbody's from all tables will be selected, then add other conditions.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnG5w/

Comment: `:first` will get the first element in the jQuery wrapped set, not the first in each table.

Comment: I'd implore on you to read that more thoroughly :p : `Description: Selects the first matched element.` May I also suggest you read this too: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/ ? `While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent.`

Comment: Thanks for correction! :D I just realized that first-child and first are different.

Comment: No biggie. Took me quite a while to realize that myself. :p